# How can we add approval button field on view of a list in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a requirement where I want to add a button called approve on the bottom of read item list page. This is something when I click on approve button should change the status of list using whatever (javascript, workflow).

Please suggest how can I do this with the existing list. I have attached the screenshot below

[image]

I'll be very grateful for all of your advise

Answer (score 0):

If you open a list in SharePoint designer. There is a section called Forms. You can use it to edit existing (add/edit/view) form or add a new one.

[image]